# zsh: display reverse history number

Tags: zsh

The bang history mechanism allow to specify a backward relative command, like `!-2` to relaunch the penultimate command. That's fine but if you launch `history`, you will only have the command serial number, which depending of your history length may be far longer.

So what I would like is a way to define a command `extended_history` which print

```
-5 12342 print example
[…]
-2 12345 print foo
-1 12346 print bar
```

Comment: I'm genuinely surprised `zsh` doesn't have this as a built-in option!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least on linux there a the tools `tac` (which prints lines in reverse order) and `nl` (which numbers lines).

So this should do the trick although without leading `-`:

```
extended_history () {
    history "$@" | tac | nl | tac
}
```

If you really want the `-`

```
extended_history () {
    history "$@" | tac | nl | tac | sed 's/^\( *\)\([0-9]\)/\1-\2/'
}
```

Comment: For some reason, the good reverse number have a shift a 2, so here is what I use successfully : `history "$@" |tac | nl -v 2 |sed -e 's/\([0-9]\)/-\1/' |tac`.

Answer (score 2):

`history` is a synonym for `fc -l`, and I'm not aware of a method using `fc` to show what you want. It's almost certainly possible to extend `zsh` to provide such a command, although I'm not quite up to writing one. A simple `awk` command can process the output of `history`, though:

```
history | awk "{print \$1-$HISTCMD, \$0}"
```